# Ubuntu on MacbookPro: how to get a support for 802.11a/n (5GHz) with chip broadcom 4331?

Tags: wireless, macbook-pro

I have been having problems with N mode. When I execute iwconfig get `wlan0 IEEE 802.11b/g`
and when I boot in Mac os my wireless card info is :

`Firmware Version:   Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 5.100.198.104.5)

Supported PHY Modes:    802.11 a/b/g/n`
And I am able to connect to N mode wireless network. But on ubuntu, this has been a problem for me when trying to connect to access point with phy mode N. 
After some research I found on the linux [wireless documentation](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43) that

`802.11a/n (5GHz) modes and power management are not yet supported HT phy cards (4331)`

Is there a way to get it to work?